# Haskell simple If-then-else error

Tags: haskell, if-statement

I'm really new to Haskell and programming in general. I'm trying to add up the contents of a list without using the `sum` function from Data.List. Here's what I've got so far:

```
module Summ
    where
summ :: [Int] -> Int
summ xs = 
  if null xs == False
    then let y = x + (head xs)
         let xs = tail xs
    else print y
```

I'm pretty sure there's a lot wrong with this code, but for now the latest error is "parse error on input" for the `else` statement. What's wrong?

Comment: `y` is defined in the first branch of your expression, but used in the second half. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: I was thinking that I could use `y` as sort of storage for the expressions I'm using to add up the elements of the list. I couldn't think of another way to do it...

Comment: Take a look at [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters), it will walk you through basics of syntax and problem solving.

Comment: I've been teaching myself with that and @haskellbook, any other good resources?

Comment: Remember that you're working in a *purely functional language* now. There's no such thing as "storage" or "variables" (at least, not in the usual sense). It's a huge adjustment to make, but in order to program efficiently in Haskell, you have to get used to that paradigm shift.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax for a `let` expression is `let BINDINGS in EXPRESSION`, e.g.

```
let x = 21 in x + x
```

It's probably complaining about `else` because it was expecting to see `in`.

There's a form of `let` without `in`, but that only works in `do` blocks (or list comprehensions).

Comment: A previous error that showed up was when I didn't have either `let`. What is an alternative that would still do those operations?

Comment: @VeganJoy What do you mean by "those operations"? Alternative to what?

Comment: I was referring to the expressions after `let` in both cases where I used it, and I don't really know a lot of functions. What else could I use there, or is `in` applicable here?

Comment: @VeganJoy I have no idea what you're trying to do there. You're defining `y` to be the sum of `x` and the first element of `xs`, but `x` doesn't exist. Then you're defining `xs` to be its own tail. I can't tell you what to use instead because I don't understand what you're trying to do or how any of this would help you with summing up a list.

Comment: Um... I don't know what I was thinking with `x`. I'm trying to take the first part of the list, add it to a variable, then get rid of the first element of `xs` and repeat until it's empty. Once it's empty I planned on having it print the variable which had been added to.

Comment: @VeganJoy That's not how Haskell works. You can't modify variables.

Comment: Uh oh... I think I'll go back to reading for a while, thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 4):

That doesn't look quite right to me. [`print`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:print) returns `IO ()`, which isn't `Int`, and the `let` section doesn't seem to lead up to an expression at all, and `x` wasn't defined. Were you attempting to write a recursive function?

```
summ [] = 0
summ (x:xs) = x + summ xs
```

The recursion isn't syntax; this simply uses two partial function definitions with pattern matching. One of them calls `summ` again, which is recursion, and eventually (given a finite list) that call will lead to the simpler, non-recursive function. The pattern also deconstructs the list into head and tail, so the function is equivalent to:

```
summ xs = if null xs
          then 0
          else head xs + summ (tail xs)
```

Note that both `then` and `else` branches are expressions of the same type.

Each of these definitions have type `summ :: Num t => [t] -> t`

Comment: I've seen the recursive syntax before but I don't know how it works. Can you elaborate? Edit: Also in the third line where I'm defining the types should that be a `IO ()` instead of `Int`?

Comment: @VeganJoy You shouldn't have an `IO` anywhere in your `summ` function. The compiler may have suggested that, because you had a stray `print` call in there, but you don't want to `print` inside your `summ` function; you want to simply return the value and let `main` print it out or do whatever it wants to it.